# Terminal run dalvikvm with am.jar

Tags: android, dalvik

I'm trying to start an installed app with dalvikvm in terminal. It doesn't work if I try to do this just so:

```
dalvikvm -cp /system/app/Calculator.apk com.android.calculator2/.Calculator
```

Then comes failure message : `dalvikvm cannot find a main class`

So I tried to run an "am start" in dalvikvm:

```
dalvikvm -cp system/framework/am.jar com.android.commands.am.Am
```

It really works. But if I trying then to start an app:

```
dalvikvm -cp system/framework/am.jar com.android.commands.am.Am start -n com.android.calculator2/.Calculator
```

it doesn't work.

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. You cannot run an android application from the terminal. In your
   first command, it would execute a static void main(String[]) method
   in the Calculator class, if there were one. It's not possible to
   "execute" an application in this manner.
2. Using am is the correct way to start a specific activity from the terminal. You can simply use the provided "am" script (/system/bin/am). Or at least look at that script to see how to correctly invoke am.

For example, `am start -n com.android.calculator2/.Calculator` should do what you want

Comment: Thanks. But I want to start from dalvikvm an app. And I think that could be possible. If I do `dalvikvm -cp system/framework/am.jar com.android.commands.am.Am` and I become the same messages as when i give in terminal just `am -help` . So I want just to start am from dalvikvm and the to give am as command to start my app. I know that your way i simpler but I need It becouse I want to modify dalvikvm and start my dalvikvm as app over existing dalvikvm

Comment: You are probably going to want to look at zygote, and how android applications are started at a lower level. I don't believe simply executing the am command from your modified version of dalvik will do what you want. If I were guessing, you would probably need to start your android app as per usual, via the normal dalvik, and then use the exec syscall to load and execute your new dalvikvm instance, passing in the various handles etc. that an android application needs, similarly to the way the zygote process works.

Comment: Also note that this is most likely a very bad idea. All android processes share some common memory, that you won't be able to take advantage of. For example, all the framework classes are loaded once, and every dalvik process has a view into that same piece of shared memory. Your new dalvik vm instance will likely need to load all these framework classes itself, thus causing excessive memory usage for your app.

Comment: I know that is not such a good idea, but i will be very happy, if I could to run am and then for example a Calculator with dalvikvm. but if i try to `dalvikvm -cp /system/framework/am.jar com.android.commands.am.Am start -n com.android.calculator2/.Claculator` it doesnt work. What do I wrong? My idea is at first to run my modified dalvikvm as an app with this commando.

Comment: When you use am to start an application, all that happens is that it sends an intent to the android system, which then starts the application like usual - it's the same as if you had clicked the application's icon in the launcher. The application does *not* run in the same process where you invoked am.

Comment: `The application does not run in the same process where you invoked am` Hmm... and why? I doesnt find anything with start a new process in Am.java or in ActivityManagerNative.java

Comment: The new process is spawned off of the zygote process. The only thing am does in this case is deliver an intent to the android system, which then does a bit of magic and a new application process is forked off from the zygote process, running the new android application.

Comment: Hmm..okay thanks ....So I would like to try it with exec...If I have understood correctly, I would try to implement my app with NDK and in my app would be a syscall exec...then I can execute my modificated dalvikvm?

Comment: That's the general idea - but be aware that it's probably not going to be an easy task to get it to work. This is a very advanced (and hacky!) solution, that will require a deep understanding of how android applications are started.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it ...Do you have a some good links to read how the android apps are started?

Answer (score 0):

You can run dalvikvm headless with [vogar](http://code.google.com/p/vogar/). You'll have to build it from SVN; the prebuilt jar is out of date!

Comment: Hmm...why would I need something like that. i have an mobile phone and can use a terminal.