# What are alternative ways to launch my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-launcher

I can launch my app by:

1. Tapping on its icon in launcher
2. Registering "visible" intent-filter (I mean - user clicks for example "Send with.." then chooses my app)
3. Entering numeral code in dialer and "call" - "invisible" intent, user cannot choose app, he just enters code

Are there any other ways to launch my app? (I'm mostly interested in something else like "invisible" intent from paragraph 3).

- Assume that we have clean device only with default system apps (most popular of Google apps are also counted as default) and my app
- Ways for usual users are preferred, but more difficult approaches will be also useful
- Variants, which can be used on one device (no other devices needed to approach) are preferred, but "more-than-one-device variants" will also be useful.

Comment: If you're rooted (that's still pretty clean): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873537/terminal-run-dalvikvm-with-am-jar

Comment: @A--C I need mostly ways to launch my app for usual users (I'll edit my question), not so geeky ;) but thanks, it's also useful

Comment: app can also be launched from [browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

Comment: @Ty221 They're currently not helpful for me, because I need variants, which can be used with 1 device (you suggested sending sms and calling) and your web browser variant has been already suggested by "nandeesh" in comments. But, as you see, your variants are helpful for community, so continue to post more of them here.

Comment: @janot please write in your question : " I need only variants which can be used on one device ". We don't know what do you want to receive. Sorry for my bad English but I am not English speaker

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This is a very ambiguous question.

Comment: @DavidCaunt I want to find more ways of launching app without tapping on it's icon in launcher. Currently I use way №3 from my question. But it doesn't work on devices which don't have dialer.

Comment: So your aim is to create an app that is hidden and can only be launched by a secret method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You can also run your app from Web browser :**

```
<intent-filter>
<data android:scheme="my.special.scheme" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

---

**You can launch your app on NFC transaction :**

Into mainfest `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />`

Read more about this here : [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html)

---

**You can also register a receiver and launch app when you receive sms with secret code in it :**

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
            for (int n = 0; n &lt; messages.length; n++) {
            smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
            }

            String text = smsMessage[0].getMessageBody();

if(text = "yoursecretcode") {
//launch the app 
abortBroadcast(); //if you want to hide this messeage
 } 
            }
```

Required permission : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>`

---

**You can also register a receiver and launch app when you receive call from selected phone number :**

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener=new MyPhoneStateListener();
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
  }
}

public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
  public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){
  switch(state){

    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
      String numer = TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER;
   // launch your app if 'numer' is ...

 break;
        }
      } 
    }
```

You need to this `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission

---

**You can also use shell to do this (phone must be rooted):**

For example :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("am start -n com.android.calculator2/.Calculator");
```

---

Colleague `"Arpan"` wrote :

> Tilt Your Phone and Wave your Hand (Basically using a Proximity Sensor
>   to launch App's Intent)

I give you code sample :

```
public class SensorActivity extends Service implements SensorEventListener {
  private SensorManager mSensorManager;
  private Sensor mProximity;

  @Override
  public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
  }

  @Override
  public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
  }

  @Override
  public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float distance = event.values[0];
  if(!ss()) // LAUNCH YOUR APP IF ISN't RUNNNING
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    // Register a listener for the sensor.
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    // Be sure to unregister the sensor when the activity pauses.
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  }
}

private boolean ss() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("com.packagename.something.ActivityName".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

`"Arpan"` wrote also :

> Plug any usb devices and put an intent filter in the manifest (If usb
>   host mode available)

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        return plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    }
```

You can paste this to `Timer`

---

**I have edited Arpan's post, i added link about Gesture Search in Android® .**

---

**You can launch application using widget (when user click this, app will launch), 
I give you widget class code snipet, more you can find [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/mastering-android-widget-development-part1) :**

```
package com.helloandroid.countdownexample;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;



public class CountdownWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {


    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
            //called when widgets are deleted
            //see that you get an array of widgetIds which are deleted
            //so handle the delete of multiple widgets in an iteration
            super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
            super.onDisabled(context);
            //runs when all of the instances of the widget are deleted from
            //the home screen
            //here you can do some setup
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
            super.onEnabled(context);
            //runs when all of the first instance of the widget are placed
            //on the home screen
    }



@Override
        public void onClick() {
         //your code to launch application...       
        }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //all the intents get handled by this method
            //mainly used to handle self created intents, which are not
            //handled by any other method


            //the super call delegates the action to the other methods

            //for example the APPWIDGET_UPDATE intent arrives here first
            //and the super call executes the onUpdate in this case
            //so it is even possible to handle the functionality of the
            //other methods here
            //or if you don't call super you can overwrite the standard
            //flow of intent handling
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                    int[] appWidgetIds) {
            //runs on APPWIDGET_UPDATE
            //here is the widget content set, and updated
            //it is called once when the widget created
            //and periodically as set in the metadata xml

            //the layout modifications can be done using the AppWidgetManager
            //passed in the parameter, we will discuss it later

            //the appWidgetIds contains the Ids of all the widget instances
            //so here you want likely update all of them in an iteration

            //we will use only the first creation run
            super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }


}
```

---

**check if Headphones are plugged in**

Whenever Headphones are plugged in an intent (`ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`) will be fired. Check for this via `BroadcastReceiver` and start Acitivity

```
IntentFilter f = new IntentFilter();
f.addAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
registerReceiver(headsetPlugReceiver, f);

public BroadcastReceiver headsetPlugReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // start new Activity or do something else
    }
};
```

And in Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="activity.to.receive.headplug.event">    
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

---

Comment: Thanks, I need all available variants. Finally, I plan to create community wiki answer with all suggested variants

Comment: At least we can try to collect most of them here

Comment: most of this ways will work only after user runs app first time.

Comment: plugging in headphones also triggers an event which can be used to start a activity

Comment: keep in mind when trying to run app from web browser (I didn't know about that): http://stackoverflow.com/a/16445731/1548085

Comment: if (text = "thesecretcode"), what is the actual code needed to launch the app?

Answer (score 2):

1. Tilt Your Phone and Wave your Hand (Basically using a Proximity Sensor to launch App's Intent)
2. Screen Tap And/Or Gesture to launch an intent (you can read about this [HERE](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html))
3. Plug any usb devices and put an intent filter in the manifest (If usb host mode available)